# How to interact with UIView behind UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, uiscrollview

I was trying to replicate something similar to the new Path app in the fact that the UIScrollview houses the main content view, and when it scrolls over it shows the menus.  My current implementation is I have the menu behind the scroll view and I have a transparent UIView covering where the menu is in the scroll view.  That way when the scroll view swipes over you can fully see the menu.  Problem is, you can;t interact behind the UIScrollview.

Does anyone know how to replicate the path type of functionality or be able to interact behind a UIScrollView?

Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that is trying to accomplish this i solved it by implementing the didenddecelerating method and trimming the frame down to not cover the page UIView.

Then whenever the user begins to interact with the part of the main scrollview view the frame resizes again

Comment: An alternative solution might be to bring the menu view to the front of the view hierarchy (again in didenddecelerating).